# python-print statement :syntax error -invalid syntax;IMPORT ERROR:NO MODULE NAMED PYPARSING

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
from __future__ import print_function//////
from pyparsing import *//ERROR IN THIS LINE///////
from copy import deepcopy   def convertToCNF(exp):

print("Given formula:", exp, sep="\n", end="\n\n")
parserOutput = parse(exp)
if parserOutput == False:
    print("Not well formed formula")
    exit(0)

root = makeTreeFromParserOutput(parserOutput)
root.makeCNF()
CNF = str(root)
if CNF[0] == "(" and CNF[-1] == ")": CNF = CNF[1:-1]
print("CNF for the formula is:", CNF, sep="\n")
```

This code shows an error in print statement which is near `sep="\n",end="\n\n")` can anyone please tell me whats the error?

Comment: Hint: You're using `python3` syntax.

Comment: Don't run Python 3 code in Python 2.

Comment: If you have a new question then open a new question.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `from __future__ import print_function` in python-2 to enable yourself to use python3 print feature.

Answer (score 1):

You're using the `print` function from Python 3 with a Python 2.x interpreter. You can import the new function with the following line:

```
from __future__ import print_function
```

... or change your `print` and use the classic Python 2.x print statement:

```
print "Given formula:\n %s\n" % exp
```

Comment: from __future__ import print_function
from pyparsing import *//ERROR IN THIS LINE SAYING IMPORT ERROR:NO SUCH MODULES
from copy import deepcopy